# From 2D shapes to one word

Tags: visual, lateral-thinking

There is a single word association to the image.

[image]

Comment: Ok. Yes, it is.

Comment: It is a novel type of a difficult abstraction puzzle designed by me. Feel free to guess answers. I can only assess the quality and weaknesses of the question after some feedback...obviously:)